# SSH connect remote machine failed even inputting right password

Tags: ssh

I use `ssh`(local macOS) to connect the remote machine(Ubuntu) and I put the public key in the remote machine in order login without inputting password. Today I connect the machine failed even inputting right password, the debug information is as follows

```
$ ssh -vvv  wqiu@scse-gpu1 
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to scse-gpu1 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1libressl
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1libressl pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to scse-gpu1:22 as 'wqiu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts:45
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from scse-gpu1
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:gE7Jt2BM5QfmjAfcNzr6CA7ZxSJBq6VbRHRhSeDfZEY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts:45
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from scse-gpu1
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 155.69.144.27
debug1: Host 'scse-gpu1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/known_hosts:45
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fb16b50b1e0)
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug2: key: /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x7fb16b60ab80)
debug2: key: /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x7fb16b410d80)
debug2: key: /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_xmss (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:qUoj6ZOOx0hqDWWKJwVTa/TJEKMxDu6wMsgN2rYy0yI /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: ECDSA SHA256:vBdUgqKuo8zQv2IuU/9ydvqvguJFitzuZ/ExE4GCOHU /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:A7msUJqrTiIKp4pOBti763vycNZKgjaI0CQvH631WEA /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
wqiu@scse-gpu1's password:
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It seems like you are missing the private key of `/Users/qiuwei/.ssh/id_xmss`.

Comment: @harrymc but xmss is not a type of private key. right?

Comment: Just pointing to an error message.

Comment: What key file is ssh supposed to use to authenticate to this particular server?